# Use of 'in' with 'ease'

Tags: word-usage

"We took our friend's car and explored the region **in** total ease."

Is this sentence correct or shall I replace **in** with **with**?

I read online that **In** is:
-Used for unspecific times during a day, month, season, year

-Used to indicate a location or place

-Used to indicate a shape, color, or size

-Used to express while doing something

-Used to indicate a belief, opinion, interest, or feeling

Does any of the above cases fit the situation? I am not sure. Kindly help!

Comment: '*in comfort*' / '*with ease*'

Comment: Preposition usage is bewilderingly complex: 'with ease' here is the correct choice if you mean 'without any difficulty'; 'in total ease' is the correct choice if you mean 'in a state of relaxation, restfulness and tranquility'.

Answer (score -1):

#### Ease

---

TL;DR: "***In ease*** is an incorrect method of expressing "***With ease***".

> *"We took our friend's car and explored the region in total ease."*

Yes, replacing "**in**" with "**with**" is the correct thing to do.

> *"We took our friend's car and explored the region with total ease."*

Alternatively, you could use the word "**easy**" as in...

> *"We took our friend's car and easily explored the region."*

or rephrasing the sentence as in...

> *"We took our friend's car and with total ease, explored the region."*

Comment: I don't accept the implication of your first statement. While it is correct in that 'in ease' and 'with ease' don't have the same meaning, the implication that "We took our friend's car and explored the region in total ease." is unacceptable is disingenuous. 'With ease' means 'without difficulty', 'in ease' means 'in a state of comfort / relaxation'. There are numerous examples of 'in ease' and 'in total ease' on the internet. The sense of ease involved is [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ease) 5. A state of rest, relaxation, or leisure: _He took his ease by the pond_ [_living in ease_]